# FiveM server, table index is nil && attempt to index a nil value (local, xPlayer)

Tags: lua, fivem

So i got some plugins for my server and keep getting these two errors.

these are my two codes.

1: table index is nil,

```
ESX.RegisterServerCallback('esx_weashop:requestDBItems', function(source, cb)

  MySQL.Async.fetchAll(
    'SELECT * FROM weashops',
    {},
    function(result)

      local shopItems  = {}

      for i=1, #result, 1 do

        if shopItems[result[i].name] == nil then
          shopItems[result[i].name] = {}
        end

        table.insert(shopItems[result[i].name], {
          name  = result[i].item,
          price = result[i].price,
          label = ESX.GetWeaponLabel(result[i].item)
        })
      end
      
      if Config.EnableClipGunShop == true then
        table.insert(shopItems["GunShop"], {
          name  = "clip",
          price = GunShopPrice,--Config.EnableClip.GunShop.Price,
          label = GunShopLabel--Config.EnableClip.GunShop.label
        })
        end
        
        if Config.EnableClipGunShop == true then
        table.insert(shopItems["BlackWeashop"], {
          name  = "clip",
          price = BlackWeashopPrice,--Config.EnableClip.BlackWeashop.Price,
          label = BlackWeashopLabel--Config.EnableClip.BlackWeashop.label
        })
        end
      cb(shopItems)

    end
  )

end)
```

2: attempt to index a nil value (local, xPlayer)

```
AddEventHandler('esx:playerLoaded', function(playerId, xPlayer)
    MySQL.Async.fetchAll('SELECT status FROM users WHERE identifier = @identifier', {
        ['@identifier'] = xPlayer.identifier
    }, function(result)
        local data = {}

        if result[1].status then
            data = json.decode(result[1].status)
        end

        xPlayer.set('status', data)
        TriggerClientEvent('esx_status:load', playerId, data)
    end)
end)
```

Comment: This is a common error with ESX resources and mostly happens because it isn't properly initialized. A quick workaround for this is to use ['@identifier'] = GetPlayerIdentifiers(playerId)[1] instead of ['@identifier'] = xPlayer.identifier

Answer (score 0):

### @1  table index is nil,

Well the first error tells you that you're using a nil value as table index.
I can't tell you which one because you failed to post the entire error message with line numbers.

It is caused by something like `a = b[c]` or `a = {[c] = b}` where `c` is `nil`.

So either `result[i].name` or `result[i].item` is `nil` when used to index `shopItems`

### @2 attempt to index a nil value (local, xPlayer)

This is more obvious. `xPlayer` is `nil` hence you may not index it as in `xPlayer.identifier`

So either ensure that `xPlayer` is never `nil` or only index it if it is indexable.

A quick look into the [esx manual](https://esx-framework.github.io/es_extended/client/events/playerloaded/) shows

```
RegisterNetEvent('esx:playerLoaded')
AddEventHandler('esx:playerLoaded', function(playerData)

end)
```

So according to the manual there is only one argument. You have two which akes the second one `nil` when the function is called with parameter.

Comment: what do i have to change in the first error exactly?

Comment: @JayvanVeen well do whatever is necessary so you won't use nil as a table value. either by making sure the value is not nil or by making sure you don't use it as a table index, if it is nil. the rest is upt to you, I don't know what is in that database, but it looks like it's not what you expect